# In Kotlin Programming language importance of varargs in terms of uses

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

Let me know what is the importance of varargs in Kotlin, if there is any document or some useful links. Please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`vararg` parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) allow for functions that accept variable number of arguments in a natural way, i.e. without creating an array or a collection first, filling it with the items, and only then passing it, compare:

<sub>If there were no `vararg` parameters:</sub>

```
val items = ArrayList<String>().apply { add("foo"); add("bar"); add("baz") }
qux(items)
```

<sub>With `vararg`:</sub>

```
qux("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

This is particularly useful for initializing collections and other containers, and there are numerous functions for that in `kotlin-stdlib`, such as `arrayOf(...)`, `listOf(...)`, `setOf(...)`, `mapOf(...)`, `sequenceOf(...)` and more.

To see the usages in `kotlin-stdlib`, search for the word 'vararg' in the [API reference pages](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) (there's a lot in packages `kotlin.collections`, `kotlin.text`).

Basically, if there is a function accepting a collection that a user might frequently call with only a few items (and choose the items right before the call), it makes sense to provide a `vararg` overload for that function.